# I am getting an error "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException : External table is not in the expected format."

Tags: c#, excel

I am getting this error when I try to read `.xls` first and `.xlsx` second.
The connection string which I am using is:

```
public string GetConnectionString(string DataFile)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> props = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(DataFile);

    props["Provider"] = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;";
    if (extension == ".xlsx")
        props["Extended Properties"] = "Excel 12.0;";
    else
        props["Extended Properties"] = "Excel 8.0;";
    props["Data Source"] = DataFile;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> prop in props)
    {
        sb.Append(prop.Key);
        sb.Append('=');
        sb.Append(prop.Value);
        sb.Append(';');
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Could someone please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Looks like you double your delimiting `;` - you have them in your props values and add them to your StringBuilder.

Comment: According to [Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/) it should be `"Excel 12.0 Xml;"` ... yours would only work for .xslb files.

Comment: Hi Filburt,   Thanks for your reply. I tried even with "Excel 12.0 Xml;". But still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: One more thing you can check is, if adding the `HDR=Yes;` property (Header Data Row) makes any difference ... and of course examining the actual file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is working in Chrome but not working with IE

Comment: If i use HDR = Yes i am getting ISAM issue